# Azure OpenAI AND Summarize an article (abstractive) with C# and TypeScript

Tags: azure-openai

I want to give users the ability to summarize long text so I started with an example from the  Azure AI Studio. Completions playground
it works fine in the studio
[image]

But then I try the code in Typescript and in C# and always get 1 choice with text:"" and finishReason:'stop'

The code is the one given by the studio for C# and from customizing the the https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/ai-services/openai/includes/javascript.md code example.

Is there any thing else I can do for it to work?